# Retroactively ordering actors' concurrent activity on disjoint sections of a data-structure

Tags: graphs, programming-languages, distributed-systems, partial-order

> Hi! I'm new here, a *terrible* computer-scientist, and have no idea what I'm doing; I'm more expecting / hoping for links to research on algorithms or data-structures that contribute to problems like this, than a straightforward answer (I don't even know how to properly ask the question.)

In some programming-language work of mine, I've got a ginormous, homogenous, directed graph, on disjoint subgraphs of which multiple actors operate concurrently.

One such operation is to add an element to an ordered set, `supplicants`, on a given node (it's a behaviour to declare “I'm waiting for write-access to this structure”, basically.) That membership is cascaded through the graph to some extent (i.e. adding an element to $a$'s `supplicants`, when $a⇸b$, places that same element in $b$'s `supplicants` as well.)

Now, normally, in my situation, the above bit where these two subgraphs are disjoint is guaranteed — *at the time*. However, there's an edge case¹ where two such subgraphs both have different values added to `supplicants` while disjoint, *and are then joined*. In this situation, I'm not sure how to deterministically order the two sets of `supplicants` amongst one-another.

---

I've heard of things like vertex clocks that I'd hoped might help with this, but after looking into it a bit today, none of the mechanisms I'm aware of are very helpful in this situation. The actors are unaware of eachother working ‘adjacently’ (or soon-to-be-adjacently, when they're joined). To *make* them aware of eachother would defeat the point (i.e. if participant $\text{foo}$ had to walk over (all|most) of the graph leaving `supplicants` hints that currently-working-disjoint-but-maybe-someday-not participants could find, and order themselves against, would be as pointless as just having a single globally-locked set shared amongst all threads); so I'm looking for some sort of lockless algorithm or distributed-systems solution for them to collaborate without(?) explicit communication.

---

1. (i.e., all of programming. `:P`)

Comment: What exactly is the requirement on the joined ordering? Is just determinism enough (i.e. any new ordering is fine, as long as it's consistent with the old orderings and deterministic)? Can the elements have some kind of globally unique ids, which could be used for the new ordering?

Comment: Do you have synchronized clocks among all of the machines?  Can you use a timestamp?  With GPS in some cases it's reasonably feasible to get extremely precise time synchronization.

Comment: I don't think I can dictate the latter — this is intended to be a distributed system, which can be embedded in lots of other pieces of software or run on lots of diverse systems;

Comment: As for the former, the *goal* is to achieve input-order (i.e. if mutator-A adds an item first, it should be represented first in `supplicants`.) — but anything deterministic would be a step up, I think, right now. And all items *do* have GUIDs, although those are defined elsewhere and not ordered in any way,